# how to remove standard background color of text in a div

Tags: html, css

**EDIT: Solved it. I had to change from the tag html to body { background. Thank you for your help everyone**

I've searched on here and on google but I only get the opacity example, if I use opacity 0 then the text disappears too.

I have a html background meaning the complete page and in the code I've placed a div with a h1 and p tag with some text and then a white box-like background around the div of the text appears and I can't remove it.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header-pris">
<h1>Pris alternativ:</h1>
<p>Skulle du vilja pröva enstaka timmar eller kanske tom mer timmar än vad           som anges nedan så går det självklart också att annordna, kontakta oss direkt på 
<a href="mailto:info@vanorden.se"> info@mail.se</a></p>
</div>
</div>

.header-pris {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:none;
}
```

tried with none as color but that doesn't do it so I don't know where I'm doing wrong or what the correct command should be to have no background on the div with the text so that you can see the image background

Comment: Have you tried setting `background-color: transparent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text doesnt have a default background-color, it might be being set somewhere else in your CSS, use a property inspector in a browser to check which styles are applied

```css
            body {
              background-image: url('http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/1111/large/feline-influenza-all-about-cat-flu-5239fffd61ddf.jpg');
            }
            
            .header-pris,.header-pris-2 {
                text-align:center;
            }

            .header-pris-2 p {
                background-color: white;
            }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-pris">
      <h1>Pris alternativ:</h1>
      <p>Skulle du vilja pröva enstaka timmar eller kanske tom mer timmar än vad som anges nedan så går det självklart också att annordna, kontakta oss direkt på 
        <a href="mailto:info@vanorden.se"> info@mail.se</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="header-pris-2">
      <h1>Pris alternativ:</h1>
      <p>Skulle du vilja pröva enstaka timmar eller kanske tom mer timmar än vad som anges nedan så går det självklart också att annordna, kontakta oss direkt på 
        <a href="mailto:info@vanorden.se"> info@mail.se</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Man do I feel stupid ....I saw your sample and noticed you put body with background and I had put html ....changed to body and it solved itself. Thank you a lot evil

Comment: Live and learn, it's never occurred to me to try adding things to the html tag, you've inspired me to test!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's `background-color:none;` a valid property. Try using

`background-color: transparent;`

Answer (score 0):

Just because this is another way of doing it.

You can use `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);`

The `a` is for `alpha`, it sets the opacity.

But the `background-color: transparent;` is the way to go.

Don't worry Nalin, I upvoted your answer since it is more correct :)

Comment: yeah tried with opacity too, should have said it but then the text goes transparent too =/

Answer (score 0):

Nalin is correct, background-color: none is not valid. You also need the closing curly brace.

```
.header-pris {
   text-align:center;
   background-color: none; /* W3 will display error */
}

.header-pris {
   text-align:center;
   background-color: transparent; /* Use this instead */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Nalin said, I think you should do `background-color:transparent;`.